# preg_replace everything but content within bbcode

Tags: php, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm trying to replace everything in my content with empty space except the content within my bbcode (and the bbcode itself).

This is my code to eliminate my bbcode.
The BBCode is just a little helper to identify important content.

```
$content = preg_replace ( '/\[lang_chooser\](.*?)\[\/lang_chooser\]/is' , '$1' , $content );
```

Isn't it possible to just negate this code?

```
$content = preg_replace ( '/^[\[lang_chooser\](.*?)\[\/lang_chooser\]]/is' , '' , $content );
```

Cheers & thanks four your help!

**EDIT**
*here is my solution* (sorry, I can't answer my own question at the moment)

```
$firstOcc = stripos($content, '[lang_chooser]');
$lastOcc = stripos($content, '[/lang_chooser]');
$content = substr($content, $firstOcc, $lastOcc + strlen('[/lang_chooser]') - $firstOcc);
$content = preg_replace('/' . addcslashes('[lang_chooser](.*?)[/lang_chooser]', '/[]') . '/is', '$1', $content);
```

I think it's not the best solution, but its working for the moment.
Maybe there is a better way to do it ;-)

Comment: Did you have a look at preg_match like I proposed? I think it is more correct than what you have now. As well your question seems to indicate you want to keep the bbcode... your solution throws it away. Also, if you already use substring to get part of your string, what purpose does preg_replace serve? Regular expressions are there to make it easier to find offsets in strings...

Answer (score 2):

The ^ character does not negate except for in character classes. It means match the beginning of the string (or the line if you are in multiline mode).

It is possible to have negative look aheads and look backs, but not to negate entire regular expressions I think.

If you just want to replace a string by part of that string, use preg_match and assign the matches array to your text

```
if( preg_match ( '/(\[lang_chooser\].*?\[\/lang_chooser\])/is', $content, $matches ) )

    echo $matches[ 0 ]; // should have what you want
```

For readability I use addcslashes to escape the / and [:

```
if( preg_match ( '/' . addcslashes( '([lang_chooser].*?[/lang_chooser])', '/[]' ) . '/is', $content, $matches ) )
```

The best part of addcslashes is that you can take any regular expression (from a variable, from a search box value, from config) and safely call preg functions without worrying about what delimiter to use.

You probably also want the u modifier for unicode compliance unless for some strange reason you don't use utf-8:

```
if( preg_match ( '/' . addcslashes( '([lang_chooser].*?[/lang_chooser])', '/[]' ) . '/isu', $content, $matches ) )
```

---

In the mean time I improved the addslashes approach a bit. It allows to use string literals in regular expressions without worrying about meta characters. Xeoncross pointed out preg_quote. It might still be nice to have an escape class like this, so you can take a fixed delimiter from somewhere to keep your code neater. Also you might want to add other regex flavors at some point or be able to catch future changes to preg_quote without changing the rest of your codebase. Currently only supports pcre:

```
class Escape
{
    /*
     * escapes meta characters in strings in order to put them in regular expressions
     * 
     * usage:
     * pcre_replace( '/' . Escape::pcre( $text ) . '/u', $string );
     * 
     */

    static
    function pcre( $string )
    {
        return

            preg_quote( $string, '/' )

        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,

hmmm ... ok I thought it's possible to negate a whole regexp. 
Do you know another way to solve my problem?

Maybe I have to explain what I wanna do:

_I have **one** content for **two** pages_, on the first page I have to display only the language chooser and on the second page I have to display only the other content.

That sounds weired, I know ;-)

Comment: Why didn't you use `preg_quote()`?

Comment: @Xeoncross You are absolutely right. I didn't know about that function... I'll update the answer.